# AngularJS select a single table cell in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to be able to click a table cell in `ng-repeat` to select it (or toggle "on/off" with CSS) but I'm getting stumped and could use some help.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in game.rows">
    <td ng-repeat="word in row.words">{{word}}</td>
</tr>
```

The `td`'s are seeded by an API with words for a game.

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('CardCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.game = {};

       $http.get('/api/games/new').success(function(game) {
           $scope.game = game;
        });
    });
```

What I'd like to do is be able to click the `td` similar to how `toggleClass` in jQuery works, being able to toggle a CSS class on the individual `td`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily toggle the class with ng-class directive in below manner:

```
<td ng-repeat="word in row.words" ng-class={yourClassName:toggle} ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{word}}</td>
```

It will toggle yourClassName with every click. The 'toggle' property will be automatically generated for each td (due to scope created by angular with ng-repeat). Thus it will not effect other td.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear though , you can use `ng-click="toggle($event)"`
$event is used to get wwhere the event is triggered.
And using below function in your controller.

```
$scope.toggle = function(event){
 $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass("myClass");
}
```

can be achieved.